# Integral of $\frac{f'(x)}{x}$

Tags: integration

Can anyone please help me in solving this integral?

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{x} dx$$

I have tried integration by parts, but I cannot get an answer. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: What answer would you expect when $f$ is unknown?

Comment: @Jack, I think the OP expects an answer in terms of $f$.

Comment: Thank you. That is what @Jose said. I need an answer in terms of $f$

Answer (score 2):

There can be no general answer in terms of $f$; for instance, if $f(x)=e^x$, then $f'(x)=e^x$ and the integral
$$
\int\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx
$$
is known not to be expressible in terms of elementary functions.